# Why won't my programmatically created textview work?

Tags: java, android

'''

```
package com.example.pillappreal;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.sql.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public ArrayList<Drug> list = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<String> testList = new ArrayList<>();
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }

    public void addNewDrug(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddNewDrugActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void testMethod(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    }

    public void addNewDrug(Drug drug) {
        list.add(drug);
        if (list.size() > 0) {
            Log.d("actually works ffs", list.get(0).name);
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);

                // Create TextView programmatically.
                TextView textView = new TextView(this);
                textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                textView.setText(list.get(i).name);

                // Add TextView to LinearLayout
                if (linearLayout != null) {
                    linearLayout.addView(textView);
                }

            }
            Log.d("Mainlist", list.get(0).name);
        }
    }
}
```

'''

The textview won't actually be created in the app. I know the textview code works because when I use it to print out "test" in the onCreate method, it works. I know the list arraylist gets its objects from the helper class because Log.d shows the values in the addNewDrug method. For some reason the textView code is not working, even when I use a string instead of value from the arraylist, and i have no clue why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need an xml (name: my_list.xml) for your listView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/checkBox"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/checkBox"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/checkBox"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Then you should create a data class (name MyData.java)

```
public class MyData {
    String myText;
    boolean myBool;

    public MyData(String myText, boolean myBool) {
        this.myText = myText;
        this.myBool = myBool;
    }

    public String getMyText() {
        return myText;
    }

    public void setMyText(String myText) {
        this.myText = myText;
    }

    public boolean isMyBool() {
        return myBool;
    }

    public void setMyBool(boolean myBool) {
        this.myBool = myBool;
    }
}
```

Then you have to create an adapter (name MyAdapter.java)

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyData> {
    private ArrayList<MyData> dataSet;
    private  Context context;
    private  int resource;


    public MyAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<MyData> dataSet) {
        super(context, resource, dataSet);

        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.dataSet = dataSet;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);

        TextView textView = rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        CheckBox checkBox = rowView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        textView.setText(dataSet.get(position).myText);
        checkBox.setChecked(dataSet.get(position).myBool);

        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                // do something here
            }
        });

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

And finally you can use your data :) (I mad it in the MainActivity)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    MyAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        test();
    }

    private void test() {

        ArrayList<MyData> myList = new ArrayList<>();
        MyData data1 = new MyData("Text1", true);
        MyData data2 = new MyData("Text2", false);

        myList.add(data1);
        myList.add(data2);

        adapter = new MyAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.my_list, myList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

Comment: If it helps you don't forget to accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to create a TextView programmatically?
You can hide and show the TextView with visibility.

If you want add new TextViews based on a user event, you can use ListView or RecyclerView

Comment: I'm making an app that allows users to track medicine they need to take. Since I want users to be able to add as many medicines as they want, I figured textview would need to be programmatically created. I didn't know about listview, thanks! I'll look into it.

Comment: I belive you need a simple listView or a RecyclerView :)

Comment: Is there a way to make a listview that has a checkbox attatched? Or would I have to programatically add that in? Each list item would need a checkbox next to it eventually

Comment: Yes. But in this case you have to make your own adapter and layout. I will made an example for you

Comment: I posted a new comment with a complete listView example what contains checkbox

Comment: In Android if you want to add items dynamically I recommend to use ListView or RecyclerView. You can do your own list. So You can add any items like TextView or CheckBox etc. If you want to save the data for the user I can recommend the ObjectBox. It is a fast and easy to use library: https://docs.objectbox.io/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

ListView sample

xml:

```
   <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Java code:

```
    ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
    test();
}

private void test() {
    ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
    arrayList.add("abcd");
    arrayList.add("1234");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```